# ¿Como validar las horas en formato HH:MM:SS mediante un INPUT TEXT con JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo 3 campos, día, hora inicio y hora fin.

Quiero validar que la hora sea entre 09:00 y 12:00 hrs para la hora de inicio y de 13:00 - 18:00 hrs para la hora de fin, el problema es que necesito validar con formato HH:MM:SS y es un INPUT text.

```
<div>
   <select class="dia sel tf w-select" data-name="Selecciona Una Opcion 2" id="txtTipoPropiedad" name="txtTipoPropiedad">
       <option value="0" selected>Día</option>
       <% for (int i = 0; i < dia.length; i++) {                                                    
            out.println("<option value=\"1\">" + dia[i] + "</option>");
          }
       %>
   </select>
   <input class="porc right tf w-input" id="node_i" maxlength="256" name="h_ini" placeholder="09:00 - 12:00 hrs" required="required" type="text">
   <input class="porc right tf w-input" id="node_f" maxlength="256" name="h_fin" placeholder="13 - 18:00 hrs" required="required" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Lo que tienes escrito es java, no javascript

Comment: @EduardoSebastian ya edite la pregunta, no coloque ese dato al inicio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo necesitas usar los métodos:

```
getHours()
getMinutes()
getSeconds()
```

Cada uno te proporcionará las horas, minutos y segundos independientemente y despues lo puedes concatenar a una cadena como aquí:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',m);

function m(){
var fecha = new Date();
var horas = fecha.getHours();
var minutos = chequearNumero(fecha.getMinutes());
var segundos = chequearNumero(fecha.getSeconds());
var divHora = document.getElementById('hora');
 divHora.innerHTML = horas + ": " + minutos + ": " + segundos;
}
function chequearNumero(numero){
  if(numero < 10) numero = "0" + numero;
  return numero;
}
 setInterval(m,500);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <i id="hora"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

**Entonces ya luego, lo puedes limitar a la hora, por si necesitas tareas más específicas, por ejemplo:**

```js
var time = new Date();
if(time.getHours() > 18) alert('Te pasaste de las 18(6 de la tarde)');
else alert('Aún no son las siete, date prisa!');
```